# windows8 windows explorer automatically change its view mode to "detail" and sort by "name"

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, virus-removal

windows8 windows explorer automatically change its view mode to "detail" and sort by "name" automatically every once in a while, this happens only in my download folder which is placed in the default windows 8 download directory C:\Users\"name of user"\Downloads, its some kind of virus? I do not get any other extrange sign of virus, but its really annoying have to change every time the download folder to "thumbnail" view and sort by "modificated date" Thanks Advanced.

PD: I have scan my system with Avira Antivirus and I have always the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Windows Explorer Navigation Pane, right-click on your `Downloads` folder. Make sure this is the `Downloads` folder under `This PC` and not under `Favorites`
2. Choose `Properties`
3. Click on the `Customize` tab
4. In the `Optimize this folder for:` dropdown box choose `Pictures`
5. Click the `Apply` then the `OK` buttons.

This will default the view to thumbnails (large icons), and the sorting method should save whichever option you last chose.

Different options are available, and the default one is `General items`. Choosing `General items` is what causes Windows to select the view dynamically based on an analysis of the contents. As you'll see in the `Customize` tab, you can choose whether or not you want to apply the setting to subfolders.

There's no need to edit your registry settings, which may adversely affect other folders where you're happy to let Windows choose the best view. There's no reason to enact a global change to your system because a single folder's properties need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It changes template based on extension dominance. This .reg should disable it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

Appears this only works with Vista and 7.

Comment: I have several other folders like music folder and video folders that I have set in detail mode and thumbnail mode respectively everytime, if I apply the registry that you suggest me, will I lost those settings?

Comment: No, they should stay as is. What this reg disables is windows checking what files are in the folder and changing the template  based on what the majority of file extensions are. For example if you had 20 mp4 files and 10 mp3 files, it would use the video template. If you remove 18 of those mp4 files, it would switch to music template. Windows occasionally decides to switch template for no reason. This is common in vista, less common in 7 and rare in 8.1.

Comment: Thanks Creation Edge n sptech but the problem persist, I mean, the download folder (is under this pc) is always in thumbnail view, the  problem is that sometimes sort pictures by name, and sometime sort them by modificated date, I want them to be sorted to modificated date always, I dont know why it changes to sort by name every once in a while. Any clue???? thanks advanced. PD> I have not try the registry change, I would prefer other solution if is possible, thanks advanced.

Comment: Seems the regkey only works for vista and 7 and they must have changed something in 8. I know how frustrating this 'bug' can be.  

Do you use the same view for all types of folders? If so you could set every template that CreationEdge has pointed out below to the same view and then all folders should show the same view. This was the first thing I did in Vista and 7 until I found out about the regkey.